# Calculating kWh two-phase alternating network 3 wires

Tags: electrical-engineering, power-electronics

I want to do a project to measure electrical consumption but I have the following question:

How to calculate kWh consumed in a 3-wire biphasic network?  Example: I have the following chains on the wires:

Phase 1 (127V): 2A

Phase 2 (127V): 3A

Neutral: 0.5A

How do I calculate how many kW will be consumed in 1 hour?

Comment: You have something wrong there unless you have different power factors on each line. The neutral current *has* to be the difference between the phase currents (unless you have earth leakage that you're ignoring). Tip: SI units named after a person have their symbols capitalised ('A') and are lowercase when spelled out ('ampere').

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Yes, I can have different power factors on each line or even a current leak. The point is, I want to understand how to calculate the power consumed in this system, even if it is an unbalanced system or if there is a current leak.